# Why new window is opening when Click submit button in popup?

Tags: asp.net

Hi I Opening a popup like this:

```
function openPopup() {
   RetVal = window.showModalDialog("chooseProducts.aspx", "", "dialogHeight: 330px; dialogWidth: 450px;scroll:no");
}
```

In the popup, when I click this button a new window is opening (with the popup contain):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="savingImpr" OnClientClick="window.close();"/>
```

I try to close the current popup before this new window. But this new window is display.
Could you help me, thank you!

**EDIT**

I've try to return false after the widow.close in popup, ok new window is not fired, but Onclick event not call.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="savingImpr" OnClientClick="window.close();return false;"/>
```

have you a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try `window.open`(....) ?

**Edit**
on opening parent window, set this class to your parent window, so that it will be like modalpopup behaviour

```
 .Background
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    }
```

change class `$get('dvMain').className = 'Background';`

Comment: thank u very much Muhammad, but I prefer using showModalDialog for disabling the parent window.

Comment: could u plz give the script for set the class of the parent page, I suppose it will be in Javascript?
thk u Muhammad

Comment: simpley do this $get('dvMain').className = 'Background';

Comment: thank you it is ok but I could set fields in the parent window. I need to disable this window, there is a css property for this? >Thks

Answer (score 3):

Put this:

`<base target="_self"/>`

in the page header.

Answer (score 0):

In the popup page, you need to call a javaScript function on the parent page that will close the popup page.

On parent page:

```
function openPopup() {
   RetVal = window.showModalDialog("chooseProducts.aspx", "", "dialogHeight: 330px; dialogWidth: 450px;scroll:no");
}

function closePopup() {
    //find and close your window here
}
```

On popup page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="savingImpr" OnClientClick="window.parent.closePopup();"/>
```

---

Edit: Instead of calling window.parent.closePopup onClientClick, you should add the javascript dynamically after you 'Save' your data on the server side.

Comment: I get this error in the popup:window.parent.closePopup is not a function.

on the parent I added this:
 function closePopup() {
            RetVal.close();
        }